# Is it possible to login to a google app with just cookies?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cookies, gmail

I am working on a project to read / show Gmails for different kinds of users. I've looked into the Gmail API for Python and ran the example code, but I would like to know if it's possible to authenticate such an application using cookies? I am really new to google applications but I haven't really found anything related to allowing users to auth with just their cookies. It would be highly appreciated if someone could link some resources for me to dive into if this is possible at all!

EDIT: If this is possible with requests / Imap libraries in python I wouldn't mind using that way either, I just want to be able to read / show end users emails using their cookies as auth!

Cheers

Comment: Yes it is possible but not realistic. However, cookies are specific to an origin and cannot be moved/copied to be used by another client/connection. That would be a major security problem. Instead, you must use OAuth to authenticate/authorize.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JohnHanley I am just a bit confused. I have set up the basic google example for python and it prompted me to auth by opening a new tab in my browser. Since I have google auth cookies stored in that browser I could use my account. I was just wondering if it would be possible to either 1. use the cookies from my browser directly to auth or 2. automate the process of authenticating. Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am really struggeling to really understand this all ^^'

Comment: There is a difference between is it possible and should you do it. Google does use cookies for some service authorization. If you want to use the official supported methods that have documentation and will work correctly for the typical application, you **must** use OAuth. There are two methods, user based (as in the browser) and service account based (JSON key file). There are some APIs that support API Keys, but that is getter rarely by the day.